# Difference between generating migrations through these 2 methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I am new to Rails. I want to know the difference between these two methods of generating migrations:

1. rails g migration MigrationName
2. rails g model MigrationName

Is preferred for making alterations to the tables that already exists. What is the real difference between these 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the main difference is that the second one should be `rails g model ModelName` doesn't just create a migration, but also creates a model file and a spec file for that model.  It also will most generate a create table migration, whereas with `rails g migration MigrationName`, you can just do very specific migrations such as adding an index, or adding/removing columns. Sections 2.1 and 2.2 will help you get a better grasp: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Answer (score 0):

```
rails g migration Filename parameters ...
```

This one generates a file in which you can write migration code. Like creating index or drop, ...

```
rails g model Tablename field field field:type ....
```

This on generates a file to generate a table with the give parameters.

See more when running `rails g model`